# Centos7 + httpd | Time to connect has run out

Tags: apache, apache2, centos7

recently i got a vps from 100up.org and i installed centos7. I installed apache2/httpd, i started the service, i double checked the firewall allowed ports. When done i go to the vps ip to see if it was working and it shows "Time to connect has run out" on firefox, and in other browser too.
I searched for 3 hours and i don't find anything. I tried to disable the firewall to see if it was working, same. apache2/httpd is working fine, in the logs all is good saying:

```
Starting httpd...
Started httpd
```

I think is a vps problem or the configuratione is misconfigured.
Apache2/httpd points to port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, there was a firewall options in vps options